# Speed up code to numerically simulate a game of coin tossing

Tags: performance-tuning, programming

### Description

I would like to simulate `n` games in which two players toss one coin each at the same time: If you toss a tail you will receive two tokens, if you toss a head you will only get one token.

The player who first accumulates at least `m` tokens wins; if this happens at the same time, the game will result in a draw.

### Code

I have written the following code:

```
m = 10; (* threshhold to win the game *)
n = 10^6; (* number of games simulated *)

flag1 = 0; (* # P1 wins *)
flag2 = 0; (* # P2 wins *)
flag3 = 0; (* # draws *)
flag4 = 0; (* # total throws *)

Do[
    (
        i1 = 0; (* initial score P1 *)
        i2 = 0; (* initial score P2 *)
        i3 = 0; (* initial # of tosses *)

        (* play one game until at least one player has collected m or more tokens *)
        While[i1 < m && i2 < m,
            i1 = i1 + 1 + RandomInteger[];
            i2 = i2 + 1 + RandomInteger[];
            i3 = i3 + 1
        ];

        (* keep score *)   
        If[i1 >= m && i2 >= m,
            flag3 = flag3 + 1, (* game is a draw *)
            If[i1 > i2,
                flag1 = flag1 + 1, (* P1 wins *)
                flag2 = flag2 + 1  (* P2 wins *)
            ]
        ];

        flag4 = flag4 + i3
    ), 
    n
]
```

**Could someone please kindly tell me how to modify this to make it faster?**

Comment: Possible description of the algorithm, in natural language?

Comment: Preallocate `storage` and write into it instead of expanding it successively with `Join`; each `Join` requires a copy operation. Replace `For` by `Do`. Leave away `Monitor`. And `Compile` everything in the end.

Comment: The downvote is not from me but I guess someone tried to tell you that this is not a free coding service...

Comment: I did not downvote, but I would have expected a clear explanation of what you want to do instead of just posting a code block.  Code like this does not communicate the intent behind it very well. The explanation must be in the question, not in comments.

Comment: But you are getting `+1` for each throw and `+1` conditional upon the result in your code above?

Comment: Tangential to the question but interesting: [Dynamical Bias in the Coin Toss (PDF)](https://statweb.stanford.edu/~susan/papers/headswithJ.pdf)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wrote something similar to @Okkes (+1), but with a general maximum `m`.

```
TeMgame = Compile[{{m, _Integer}},
   Block[{r = Range[m]},
      Sign[
         First[ Pick[r, UnitStep[Accumulate[RandomInteger[{1, 2}, m]] - m], 1]] -
         First[ Pick[r, UnitStep[Accumulate[RandomInteger[{1, 2}, m]] - m], 1]]
   ]], CompilationTarget -> "C", Parallelization -> True]
```

It is faster than `cf` from @gwr when `m` is larger. For example,

```
AbsoluteTiming[Sort@Tally[Table[TeMgame[200], {10^6}]]]
```

> {10.4598, {{-1, 463391}, {0, 72762}, {1, 463847}}}

`ParallelTable` on 8 kernels takes 2.5 seconds.

**Update**

Write `TeMgame3` to save the numbers of flips.

```
TeMgame3 = Compile[{{m, _Integer}},
   Block[{r},
      r = Range[m];
      {First[Pick[r, UnitStep[Accumulate[RandomInteger[{1, 2}, m]] - m], 1]], 
       First[Pick[r, UnitStep[Accumulate[RandomInteger[{1, 2}, m]] - m], 1]]}
   ], CompilationTarget -> "C", Parallelization -> True]
```

Now run the following to count the total number of flips, as well as the wins, draws, and losses.

```
AbsoluteTiming[
   With[{t = ParallelTable[TeMgame3[200], {i, 1, 10^6}]},
      {Total[Map[Min, t]], Sort[Tally[Sign[Subtract @@@ t]]]}
   ]]
```

> {2.74122, {131388986, {{-1, 463096}, {0, 73098}, {1, 463806}}}}

Your second question refers to a draw being achieved "only when both players have the same number of coins". I currently do not see how it can be otherwise...

Answer (score 7):

Some improvement with `Compile` and a slightly different "take" on the problem using [`NestWhile`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestWhile.html):

```
cf = Compile[
    {
        { m, _Integer },
        { n, _Integer }
    }, 
    Module[
        {
            game, (* vector to track a single game: { P1 tokens, P2 tokens, tosses } *)
            p1wins = {1, 0, 0, 0},
            p2wins = {0, 1, 0, 0},
            draw   = {0, 0, 1, 0},
            count  = {0, 0, 0, 1}
        },
        (* function returns vector: { # P1 wins, #P2 wins, # draws, # tosses } *)
        Total @ Table[
            (
                (* play game until at least one player has m or more tokens *)
                game = NestWhile[
                    # + { RandomInteger @ {1,2}, RandomInteger @ {1,2} , 1 } &,
                    {0, 0, 0},
                    #[[1]] < m && #[[2]] < m &
                ];
                (* keep score *)
                Which[
                    game[[1]] >= m && game[[2]] >= m, draw,
                    game[[1]] > game[[2]], p1wins,
                    True, p2wins
                ] + game[[3]] * count
            ),
            n
        ]
    ],
    CompilationTarget -> "C" (* this option requires C compiler installed *)
];

cf[ 10, 10^6]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.922876, Null} *)
```

Maybe more is possible with parallelization.

Comment: @TeM Ok, `Compile` brings this down to around 1 sec.

Comment: `1 + RandomInteger[]` is equivalent to `RandomInteger[{1, 2}]`

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:**

```
m = 10;
n = 100;
Table[Sign@
  Differences@
   Flatten[FirstPosition[#, 1] & /@ 
     UnitStep[Accumulate /@ RandomInteger[{1, 2}, {2, m}] - m]], n]
```

**Original answer**

Here is more compact one but slow, it might be improved. $\{+1,0,-1\}=\{\text{p1 wins},\text{draw},\text{p2 wins}\}$

```
   n=100;
Table[Sign@
      Differences[
       First@Flatten@Position[#, 10 | 11] & /@ 
        Accumulate /@ RandomInteger[{1, 2}, {2, 10}]], n]
```